# SimpleXML não retorna os dados do arquivo

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Estou usando [simplexml](/questions/tagged/simplexml) do [php](/questions/tagged/php) para pegar os dados de um arquivo [xml](/questions/tagged/xml), mas não retorna nada.

O que pode ser ?

```
<?php

@header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.multicinecinemas.com.br/webservice/?chave=c99e34ed77750774417e5a9d2a2f5135&tipo=cinema");

foreach($xml->filme as $filme)
{
 echo $filme->codigo;
 echo $filme->nome;
 echo $filme->horario;
 echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: A forma q vc está iterando o xml que está errada. Repare que na estrutura do arquivo vc não começa com filme, começa com cinemas > cinema > filmes

Comment: Como eu faço isto funcionar? Não manjo desses "subníveis"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para chegar a *imprimir* somente o ***filme*** precisa navegar até o *ponto correto*:

> `$xml->CINEMAS->CINEMA->FILMES->FILME`

***Por exemplo:***

```php
<?php

    $url = 'http://www.multicinecinemas.com.br/webservice/'
    $url .= '?chave=c99e34ed77750774417e5a9d2a2f5135&tipo=cinema';

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    foreach($xml->CINEMAS->CINEMA->FILMES->FILME as $filme)
    {       
        echo $filme->CODIGO;
        echo ' ';
        echo $filme->NOME;
        echo ' ';
        echo $filme->HORARIO;
        echo ' ';
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

---

Para repetir o mesmo processo para varios arquivos use uma função como está:

```php
function toPrint(array $array = array())
{
    foreach($array as $items)
    {
        foreach($items->CINEMAS->CINEMA->FILMES->FILME as $filme)
        {           
            echo $filme->CODIGO;
            echo ' ';
            echo $filme->NOME;
            echo ' ';
            echo $filme->HORARIO;
            echo ' ';
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}

$url = 'http://www.multicinecinemas.com.br/webservice/'
$url .= '?chave=c99e34ed77750774417e5a9d2a2f5135&tipo=cinema';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

toPrint(array($xml1, $xml2));
```

Comment: Deu certo.
No caso, eu preciso pegar imprimir dados de 2 arquivos xml. Como eu faria para inserir dentro de uma variáriavel $xml2 os dados do outro arquivo, dentro do foreach? Tipo: foreach($xml->CINEMAS->CINEMA->FILMES->FILME as $filme, $xml2->FILMES->FILME as $filme2)

Comment: @LeoAmaral repita o mesmo procedimento para o `xml2`, pode construir uma função para imprimir e passe os dois arquivos, vou editar e propor uma função.